# Pyspark join with mixed conditions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I have two dataframes: **left_df** and **right_df** that have common columns to join on: `['col_1, 'col_2']` , and I want to join onto another condition: `right_df.col_3.between(left_df.col_4, left_df.col_5)]`

Code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

join_condition = ['col_1', 
                  'col_2', 
                  right_df.col_3.between(left_df.col_4, left_df.col_5)]
df = left_df.join(right_df, on=join_condition, how='left')

df.write.parquet('/tmp/my_df')
```

But I got the error below:

```py
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Why I can't add those 3 conditions together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix strings with Columns. The expressions must be a list of strings or a list of Columns, not a mixture of both. You can convert the first two items to a column expression instead, e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

join_condition = [left_df.col_1 == right_df.col_1, 
                  left_df.col_2 == right_df.col_2, 
                  right_df.col_3.between(left_df.col_4, left_df.col_5)]

df = left_df.join(right_df, on=join_condition, how='left')
```

Comment: yes and I just needed to add the code below to prevent duplicated columns:
```
python
common_col = set(left_df.columns).intersection(right_df.columns)
common_col
selected_col = set(df.columns).difference(common_col)
df.select(*selected_col, left_df.gsp_group_id, left_df.profile_class_id, left_df.standard_settlement_configuration_id, left_df.time_pattern_regime_id).write.parquet('/tmp/my_df')